# Is it possible to enable replication on mysql from latest version to older version

Tags: mysql, synchronization, replication, database-replication

I have mysql 8.0.27 but there is an issue with sort_buffer which is causing exceptions now we are planning to move back to 8.0.16 which we used earlier with no issues so is it possible to keep 8.0.27 as master and 8.0.16 as slave once they are in sync we are going to make 8.0.16 as master

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. You can replicate data from/to different versions of MySQL.

MySQL supports different replication methods (depending on the version). The traditional method is based on replicating events from the source's binary log, and requires the log files and positions in them to be synchronized between source and replica. The newer method based on global transaction identifiers (GTIDs) is transactional and therefore does not require working with log files or positions within these files. These methods don’t require to be in the same version.

It supports replication from one release series to the next higher release series. For example, you can replicate from a source running MySQL 5.6 to a replica running MySQL 5.7, from a source running MySQL 5.7 to a replica running MySQL 8.0, and so on.

It could be difficult if you want to replicate data between different major versions, like 5.5 to 8.0 for example, because there could be significant changes in data types or structures, but in between minor versions or one major version, you should be fine.